# Do we have $\int_{\partial M}f\langle X,N\rangle_g dV_\tilde{g}=0$ if both $f$ and $X$ are compactly supported?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, manifolds-with-boundary, divergence-theorem

In Euclidean spaces, if a partial integration involves a function with compact support, then we won't have to include the boundary integral because it contributes nothing. More precisely, if $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n,u\in C^1(U),\phi\in C_c^\infty(U)$, then for $i=1,\ldots,n$,
$$\int_U u\phi_{x_i}dx=-\int_U \phi u_{x_i}dx.\tag{1}$$
Motivated by this fact, I'm considering a similar question with Euclidean spaces replaced by Riemannian manifolds. Let $(M,g)$ be an oriented Riemannian manifold with boundary. For any compactly supported smooth vector field $X$ on $M$, the divergence theorem states that
$$\int_M\mathrm{div}X dV_g=\int_{\partial M}\langle X,N\rangle_g dV_\tilde{g},\tag{2}$$
where $N$ is the outward-pointing unit normal vector field along $\partial M$ and $\tilde{g}$ is the induced Riemannian metric on $\partial M$. I know a manifold boundary is not necessarily a topological boundary, and maybe that's why the integration on the RHS of (2) is not trivial even though $X$ has compact support. Now, if a $\color{red}{\text{compactly supported}}$ smooth function $f$ on $M$ comes in, I'd like to know whether or not
$$\int_{\partial M}f\langle X,N\rangle_g dV_\tilde{g}=0.\tag{3}$$
Yeah, I was thinking about an affirmative answer but didn't know how to prove it. Does anyone have an idea? Thank you.

**Added:**

I was told in *Geometric Relativity* that the gradient operator $\mathrm{grad}$ and $-\mathrm{div}$ are the formal adjoints of each other, so I'm planning on showing that
$$\int_M\langle\mathrm{grad}f,X\rangle_g dV_g=\int_M f(-\mathrm{div}X) dV_g\tag{4}$$
for all compactly supported $f$ and $X$. And the book just mentioned told me to make use of the divergence theorem and the product rule
$$\mathrm{div}(fX)=\langle\mathrm{grad}f,X\rangle+f\mathrm{div}X.\tag{5}$$
Then I followed the hint to get the partial integration formula for Riemannian manifolds:
$$\int_M\langle\mathrm{grad}f,X\rangle_g dV_g=\int_{\partial M}f\langle X,N\rangle_g dV_\tilde{g}-\int_M f\mathrm{div}X dV_g\tag{6}$$
This begs the question: how come does (3) hold true?

Comment: $\langle f, X \rangle$ doesn't make sense. Why would the integral equal 0 anyway? Even in Euclidean spaces, you do still have a boundary term ...

Comment: @Mason Sorry, I was making a stupid mistake. I have edited the question. Thank you for pointing out that. Thank you.

Comment: Why would the f change anything? Can't f be equal to 1?if you move the f into the inner product, so that it multiplies X, you are asking if the integral of any field dot the outer normal is zero? Surely not: extend the outer normal to a field on the whole of M and call the result X: then the integral is the volume of the boundary.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I've edited the post. Thank you.

Comment: Since the whole manifold can be compact, adding hypotheses about compact support will not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you’ve currently phrased things, no, and you have very obvious counterexamples. For example, let $M=\overline{B(0,1)}\subset\Bbb{R}^n$ be the closed unit ball. This is obviously a smooth manifold with boundary, and it is compact, so by default every vector field is compactly supported. Consider the vector field $X$ corresponding to the identity map (i.e $X(p):=\sum_{i=1}^np^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}(p)$). This vector field can be defined on all of $\Bbb{R}^n$, and by restricting to $M$, you get a vector field tangent to $M$. The normal $N$ is just $X$ restricted to $\partial M$, so
\begin{align}
\int_{\partial M}\langle X,N\rangle\,dA&=\int_{\partial M}\langle N,N\rangle\,dA=\text{area}(\partial M)\quad\left(=\frac{2\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma(n/2)}\right).
\end{align}
So, the answer is definitely not zero.

The correct generalization of the result you quoted is the following:

> Let $(M,g)$ be a smooth ($C^2$ works) $n$-dimensional (pseudo-)Riemannian manifold (without boundary, like $\Bbb{R}^n$). Then, for any smooth ($C^1$ works) compactly supported vector field $X$ on $M$, we have $\int_M\text{div}(X)\,dV_g=0$.

Or, you can work with manifolds-with-boundaries, and require that the vector field is compactly supported in the manifold interior $\text{int}(M)$, so that the vector field vanishes on $\partial M$. In this case, by the divergence theorem, the boundary term vanishes by hypothesis.

Comment: I edited the post. Thank you.

Comment: @Wombat I gave you two ways of “fixing” the statement. The issue is not compact support. It is about imposing the condition of having no boundary, or imposing that the support lies away from the boundary.

Comment: You were right, and I found someone tackling the problem by assuming a closed manifold: the boundary integral died out by nature.